# XPath - visited or unvisited links?

Tags: xpath, hyperlink, visited

I keep track of new pages (only new, not updates to existing pages) on a site using a google search, something like https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackexchange.com&num=100&tbs=qdr:m

I then click on all links that are unvisited (blue) to make them visited (purple). This way it is easy to see when a new link appears in the list.

Now I would like to automate part (using Wachete or similar service that can check the search result page once a day or so) of this process and for this I need to detect if there are links on the page with the search results that are unvisited.

**Is that possible using Xpaths?**

Answer (score 1):

This has been disabled in browsers for security reasons. 
Source: [Mozilla Foundation Blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/).

Chrome/FF don't support `$("a:visited")`